Data management pattern for temporarily storing/retrieving excessive quantities of data
I have been tasked with creating an application to ingest raw binary data from a software-defined radio (SDR) and display it in a web frontend. One of the purposes of this app is to allow a user to take a "capture" from a radio, allowing them to download a short historical period of raw data. I am struggling with the best way to store and process this data.
The goal of this app is to be able to demonstrate frequencies well into the megahertz, requiring sample rates that could approach the gigahertz range. Given that a single complex sample requires eight bytes, the rate of ingest could easily surpass 1 GB/s. This will stretch the memory of my program. I believe it is far too great of a data rate to write to simply write to disk.
I need some advice on database systems to manage this high-volume data pattern. The important part is that no data analysis is necessary (all data is strictly binary), and some delay in data recall can be tolerated.
Edit: I realized that I should clarify better how I am thinking of storing the data. Here's the preconditions and my thoughts:

Binary data is received incrementally from the radio.
Data needs to be able to be queried in some way related to time. However, this does not necessarily mean that timestamps need to be stored. If there is little to no data loss, then the size of a required return payload can be deduced based on the number of samples requested (since each sample is known to be eight bytes).
Rather than exact timing, the important part is that data is stored in a continuous, non-lossy manner, to produce accurate waveforms. For example, supposing that data is stored in 1GB incremental records, the system can approximate how many records are needed for one request, and then trim the data server-side.
The data can be regularly flushed once a certain capacity is reached, if this is beneficial to performance. Captures need not be more than 10GB each.
Data will be associated relationally with a radio, whether this be through a table-based structure or simply an ID. (this is the easy part)


"Please help me find a system that can handle these needs, or if this data flow is even possible on a small scale." - The problem isn't choosing a database system, they all tolerate writing & reading the same amount of data equally. This is a hardware and systems design problem instead. There's not much to say about hardware, it's pretty obvious the better hardware the better performance. But from a system design perspective, we'll need more information in order to provide an answer. Particularly some way to better conceptualize what your data looks like and the use cases for it in the app.

@J.D. Thanks for your comment, I added some details about my concept for the system.

Thanks for adding more details. I'm still trying to conceptualize your use cases and the consumer side especially. Since this is binary data, it's obviously not something the consumer  will visually digest. With that said, could you please clarify further what you mean by "display it in a web frontend"?...is this binary data essentially encapsulating audio that can be listened to?...is the goal just to provide a way for the end user to select a sample that's a subset of the binary data from the radio? How would that user indicate the start and end of that sample?...by timestamp?

@J.D. I'm not sure if you are familiar with the concept of a software-defined radio, but for the sake of the concept, think of my data storage problem as representing a huge audio file at an exceedingly high sample rate (meaning TONS of data) sourced from a microphone (so live). The user only sees the data analyzed instantaneously every 1/60 sec, so that is not a bottleneck. However, the user has the option to download the past N seconds (or samples) as a raw audio file. So though not always displayed, all received live data needs to be saved to be later recalled.

@J.D. The user can only indicate the size of the payload as a delta - so the past 10 seconds or the past 10k samples (etc), reducing the storage burden of the server. This can easily be converted (based on sample rate) to an exact number of bytes, which hints to the server how much to download. How exactly the server comes up with that data, in the end, will vary based on how the data store is implemented.

Cool, thanks, that's helpful. So in simpler terms, we're dealing with a continuous audio stream that an end user will be able to listen to live and also be able to recall past parts of the stream. Will the end user typically specify the recalled audio in terms of seconds or is it typical to recall by # of samples? What is the limit to how far back they can recall data for? If I understood your original post correctly, your write speeds can be as high as 1 GB of data per second?...for how long of a time would this write rate be sustained?

@J.D. I would like to limit the amount of data the user can collect to no more than 25GB and perhaps less. This means the maximum amount of time varies with sample rate. Time can easily be converted to both # samples and total size in bytes, so whichever is simpler to recall can be used. In my head, it made sense to store data as discretely sized chunks (say 1GB), then N records could be recalled. The write speed could be as high as 1GB/s, but in that case would only be able to be sustained for less than 30 seconds given a data limit.

@J.D. Another important thing to mention is that the user has to indicate the "start" of a recording; therefore, the app does not need to constantly record data. It only needs to begin when prompted. However, this pattern will require that the data can be regularly cleared from the DB, which from my preliminary research indicates may or may not be a relatively slow operation. Which is why I asked here, hoping somebody more familiar with a variety of DB systems could help me find which system will be able to best handle my use case.
